# Send flag to cancel CopyFileEx after it has started

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am currently developing backup software, which I was using `File.Copy()` to copy files.

However `File.Copy()` doesn't have the option to cancel, so after a bit of googling I found `CopyFileEx` does. I had a look through the [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.copyfileex) docs but I can't work out how I can actually send the flag to cancel it without calling the whole function again.

Can I just set a `bool` value and reference that, and will `CopyFileEx` detect that it has changed if I change it from somewhere else?

Any help or examples appreciated.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74963/CopyFileGeneric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852(v=vs.85).aspx

> If this flag is set to TRUE during the copy operation, the operation is canceled. Otherwise, the copy operation will continue to completion.