# How is CopyFileEx's pbCancel parameter safe?

Tags: winapi, thread-safety

There are several questions posted (like [Send flag to cancel CopyFileEx after it has started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950717/)) that reference the ability to use the `pbCancel` parameter of the Win32 `CopyFileEx()` function to cancel an in-progress copy.  What is not clear to me, is why is it safe to set that boolean in another thread without any sort of synchronization mechanism (mutex, etc.)?  This functionality is really only useful if another thread sets that boolean to true, as `CopyFileEx()` blocks until the file copy is finished.

Is this relying on a peculiarity of the Windows platform?

Comment: There is no mention of another thread in the documentation. The primary way to cancel the operation is from a progress callback. You can do whatever you need from that callback, including reading a value that's modified from a different thread. Nothing keeps you from implementing any sort of synchronization or memory barriers as needed.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I didn't realize the callbacks ran in the same thread as copyfileex().  During internet research I found folks who were talking about setting it from another thread, and I figured that couldn't be safe.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: what here can be unsafe set **boolean** (in sense 0 or not 0) variable from another thread ? here of course not need any synchronization

Answer (score -2):

in case simply set boolean by sense variable (which can be 0 or not 0) without any connection with other data - not need any synchronization - for what ?!
one thread set variable to true, another thread read from variable or 0 or not 0. even if you do write and read to variable in critical section - what this change ? nothing ! thread which will be read - anyway load or 0 or not 0 from variable.

synchronization need in another cases. usually when we write to another memory locations, before store *true* in variable, and want that after another thread read *true* from variable - all another memory modification will be visible already. but in case cancel callback - no any another data

or if we write complex data to variable (not only or 0 or not 0) and this write not atomic - synchronization need for prevent read partial state. but here impossible any "partial state" by design

---

For those who not understand:

no matter are write to or read from *pbCancel* will be atomic.
in any case finally some value will be read from *pbCancel*.

if this value will be [interpreted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexw) as **TRUE** during the copy operation, the operation is canceled. **Otherwise**, the copy operation will continue to completion.

> *If this flag is set to **TRUE** during the copy operation, the operation is canceled. Otherwise, the copy operation will continue to
> completion.*

even if some *"transient state"* will be read - and so what -any way this value will be used in if/else expression and as result copy operation will be canceled or continue.

Nowhere is not specified (and this contradicts common sense) that a strict checking of 0 (*false*) and 1(*true*) will be performed and in case of any other value there will be an exception or UB.

on the contrary - it is clearly indicated that *Otherwise (ie **flag** not set to TRUE), the copy operation will continue to completion.*. no any words about exception, UB, etc

if look on declaration of `CopyFileExW`, here visible in more details how *pbCancel* value is interpreted:

```
_When_(pbCancel != NULL, _Pre_satisfies_(*pbCancel == FALSE))
_Inout_opt_ LPBOOL pbCancel,
```

so check is (and this is most native)

```
if (pbCancel == NULL || *pbCancel == FALSE)
    // continue copy
else
    // cancel copy
```

here no any *"transient state"*. here or 0 or not 0. even if you write 1 to *pbCancel* but another thread read from it say *0x5FD38FCA* - this will be interpreted as *TRUE* and copy operation will be canceled.

anyway - if you write *true* (in strict sense 1) to variable - another thread sooner or later read *1* from this variable. do this in critical section - nothing change - again only sooner or later another thread read this value. not faster.

Comment: This isn't correct. Not even for an architecture as forgiving as x86. Writing to a `BOOL` through a pointer from one thread can still have another thread observe a transient value. Simple counter example: A `BOOL` that straddles a cache line boundary.

Comment: @IInspectable - you nothing understand. what is *transient value* ?? or it will be 0 or not 0. this not depend from any cpu architecture. my answer is correct.  your comment is wrong

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. Or maybe you are, just as [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45411743/1889329). I'm sure you still believe that that answer is perfectly correct, while it is *provably* wrong. This is not something I can resolve. It's on you to learn how CPU's *really* work, and how programming languages capture that complexity by specifying a memory model over an abstract machine.

Comment: @IInspectable - again - this absolute not depend from how CPU's really work, etc. you can not or special not want understand very simply thing - thread which read from variable - read some value. this value can be 0. or can be not 0. all.if will be not 0 - copy files break. if 0 - continue. in what problem here ?

Comment: Maybe I'm just too thick to understand a *"very simple thing"*. Or maybe you make that thing sound much more simple than it is. Now, back to the original question: What would happen in case that `BOOL` variable straddles a cache line boundary? How many memory reads and memory writes would be required to update that value? If it is more than one, how probable is an atomic update to the stored value?

Comment: @IInspectable - even in this `BOOL` (4 bytes) not aligned, even if it cross cache line boundary, even if write not atomic, even if read from it not atomic - are thread which will be read - read finally some value ? can you reply for this - **some** value (dont matter what value) will be finally read ?

Comment: Sure, a thread will observe *some* value. That value may represent a transient state. If your only requirement for *"correct"* code is, that it doesn't immediately crash, then sure, you have *"correct"* code right there (possibly anyway). That doesn't coincide with my understanding of correct code. Now consider this: If [*everyone*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45411743/1889329) thinks you are wrong, you might want to evaluate the possibility that maybe you are.

Comment: @IInspectable *That value may represent a transient state.* - and so what ? here this not a problem. this value will be interpreted as *true* or as *false*. if it will be interpreted as *true* - copy break. if as *false* - copy continue.